Estimate swap rates correlation in absence of spread options
Any suggestions / pointers on how to estimate swap rates correlation in absence of spread options? Is it feasible to work it out with the correlation of forwards coming from the intersection of capfloors and swaption prices/volatility surfaces and then deduce the correlation of swap rates given the relationship between forwards and swap rates?

Your suggested procedure doesn’t work very well.  The ‘wedge’ between cap/floors and swaptions depends on the volatility term structure as well as correlation, so it is not a pure measure.
I believe it is simplest just to measure historical correlations over various observation windows and estimate the long term average.

I see thanks. So basically even the correlation of forward rates used as input for a BGM model will not be sufficient? I tried how that could work but I don't find it obvious, on top of handling instantaneous quantities as opposed to what I want to get to (meaning terminal correlation between swap rates) and that coterminal swaps are used for BGM (I am rather interested in swap rates for different maturities seen from today as opposed to swap rates with same maturity but starting at different points in the future)
